# The surface of Aizawa attractor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

[Aizawa attractor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBqbQUu-p00) creates a closed surface. Let's ignore the transient state in the beginning. I am wondering how to calculate its surface? I even don't know where to start.

The dynamic model of Aizawa attractor is
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = (z-b)x-dy\\
\dot{y} = dx+(z-b)y \\
\dot{z} = c+az-\frac13 z^3-(x^2+y^2) (1+e z)+f z x^3\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Though, it is preferred that the general form of problem is solved, 
a special case of the parameters is

\begin{align}
&\quad~a=0.95\\
&\quad~b=0.7\\
&\quad~c=0.6\\
&\quad~d=3.5\\
&\quad~e=0.25\\
&\quad~f=0.1
\end{align}

Comment: If you don't write down any equation whatsoever it is hard to answer here

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, thank you very much for this comment.

Comment: You are welcome but I didn't do anything! :-) Anyway, what do you exactly want to compute? The equations describing the attractor, or just its surface area? I suspect that the equations are very complicated.

Comment: P.S.: The video is beautiful.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, I look for an analytical solution if possible.